# Chef Kitchen (kitchen-ec2) serverspec spec failing and causing error

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra, test-kitchen, serverspec

I am learning Chef and the testing process using Kitchen with the ec2 driver and have the following serverspec file:

```
require "serverspec"

set :backend, :exec

describe "rbenv" do
  describe file("/home/ec2-user/.rbenv") do
    it { should be_directory }
  end

  describe command("rbenv versions") do
    its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }
  end
end
```

When I run `kitchen verify amazon-linux` the first test passes but the second one fails and causes an error:

```
rbenv
         File "/home/ec2-user/.rbenv"
           should be directory
         Command "rbenv versions"
           exit_status
             should eq 0 (FAILED - 1)

       Failures:

         1) rbenv Command "rbenv versions" exit_status should eq 0
            Failure/Error: its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }

              expected: 0
                   got: 127

              (compared using ==)
              /bin/sh -c rbenv\ versions

            # /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec/rbenv_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 0.05481 seconds (files took 0.30304 seconds to load)
       2 examples, 1 failure

       Failed examples:

       rspec /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec/rbenv_spec.rb:11 # rbenv Command "rbenv versions" exit_status should eq 0

       /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -I/tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec -I/tmp/verifier/gems/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib:/tmp/ver
ifier/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib /opt/chef/embedded/bin/rspec --pattern /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec/\*\*/\*_spec.rb --c
olor --format documentation --default-path /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec failed
       !!!!!! Ruby Script [/tmp/verifier/gems/gems/busser-serverspec-0.5.9/lib/busser/runner_plugin/../serverspec/runner.rb /tm
p/verifier/suites/serverspec] exit code was 1
>>>>>> Verify failed on instance <default-amazon-linux>.
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/default-amazon-linux.log for more details
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sh -c '
BUSSER_ROOT="/tmp/verifier"; export BUSSER_ROOT
GEM_HOME="/tmp/verifier/gems"; export GEM_HOME
GEM_PATH="/tmp/verifier/gems"; export GEM_PATH
GEM_CACHE="/tmp/verifier/gems/cache"; export GEM_CACHE

sudo -E /tmp/verifier/bin/busser test
']
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

I logged into the server manually and ran the same command `/bin/sh -c rbenv\ versions` and it worked fine.

Can anyone tell if there's something I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT 1**

I just discovered that when serverspec runs the command the `$PATH` variable is different from what it is when I log in manually. I added `puts ENV['PATH']` to the test and the output was this:

`/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

However, when I login manually I get this:

`/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin`

I changed the command in the test to `/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/rbenv versions` and it passed. Any idea what I need to do to make the paths work correctly here?

**EDIT 2**

So I've discovered that serverspec is running the commands as `root`, which means that the changes to `ec2-user`'s path that took place during `kitchen converge` are unavailable.

I don't know if there's a more idiomatic way to do this with serverspec, but I changed my command to this and the test now passes:

`runuser -l ec2-user -c 'rbenv versions'`

This allows `root` to run a command as another user. Unless someone knows of a better way to do this kind of test I'll add this as the answer to the question.

Comment: Try checking the output: `its(:stdout) { should eq '' }` and similar to stderr. That will display them from the rspec output.

Comment: @coderanger I just realized (haven't added to OP yet) that when serverspec runs the command the `$PATH` variable is different. I changed the command to `/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/rbenv versions` and the test passed. Any idea what I need to do to make the paths work correctly here?

Comment: ok so I've finally figured out serverspec is running the tests as `root` user...so the changes I made to `ec2-user`'s `$PATH` aren't accessible...

Comment: That is correct, kitchen expects to run everything as root to keep things standardized.

Comment: thanks @coderanger. do you know of another solution besides `runuser` that I've added to the end of the OP, or is that the best?

Comment: I usually use some form of `sudo`, but that's just laziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serverspec runs its commands as root, so changes made to any other user's path during convergence are irrelevant.

Using the Linux `runuser` command will allow `root` to run a command as another user, thereby gaining access to that user's `$PATH`:

```
runuser -l ec2-user -c 'rbenv versions'
```